# What's wrong in my code in fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

By using [This](http://jsfiddle.net/4X4YT/) i have created another tab and created another fiddle like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sf8qbv42/) .

What wrong did i do i do also include this in my code. If i need to include then how can i include the below code in jsfiddle.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use External resources on the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click External Resources from the left menu

Enter the library url one by one and click + button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the libraries from the settings cog in the Javascript box. You can check the libraries used in the fiddle you modified from the same place.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the framework that way :

[image]

First you click on "javascript" then you can add the jQuery version you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add all your external resources CDN on the left section of the webpage.

[image]